# Reference one model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to reference images in `buildings/index.html.erb`. I have:

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @buildings = Building.all
    @images = @buildings.images.all
  end
end

class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
end
```

**buildings/index.html.erb**:

```
      <% @buildings.each do |building| %>
        <% if @buildings.images.any? %>
          <% @buildings.images.name %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

I get the following error: `undefined method images for <Array:0x000001109b4680>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@buildings` is an array of `Building` objects. Every `Building` object has its `images` method. You might iterate over the `@buildings` array and call the `images` method of every member.

```
<% @buildings.each do |building| %>
  This is Building with ID <%= building.id %>.
  <% if building.images.any? %>
  ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also, you don't need the `@images` variable in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

You're not iterating over your buildings. You need to grab each one and then do what you were trying to do:

```
<%- @buildings.each do |building| %>
  <%- if building.images.any? %>
    ... 
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

You can also do:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @buildings %>
```

This will take each `Building` object and pass it to a `_building.html.erb` partial where you can then do

**_building.html.erb**

```
<%- if building.images.any? %>
  ... 
<%- end %>
```